# XNA Update in windows form?

Tags: windows, forms, function, xna

is there anyway to get the update function from XNA into a windows form? I've looked through all the examples and they all seem to focus on the draw function, unless I'm missing something in them.

*Note: I'm looking for a way to get the actual Update method from XNA, not make a custom one with stopwatches.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to host your game in some other way, you can replace the functionality from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game with your own code.

Unfortunately, this includes the Update and Draw methods.  This is why the samples you see all implement their own gametime.

Sources:

http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game_members.aspx